# How to grab list of chekboxes and send it to Action in List object?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

How to grab list of checkboxes and send it to Action in IList object? I would like to use jQuery to grab list of objects from my page, then create object and send it to action method. In action method it should be List .net object.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post you code, we can then help you with where it isn't working.

Comment: I am trying to save state of checkboxes when I am reloading partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of checkboxes in your markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c4" />
```

and a controller action which will take the values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(IEnumerable<bool> values)
{
    ...
}
```

you could invoke it like this:

```
var values = $(':checkbox').map(function () {
    return $(this).is(':checked');
}).toArray();

$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("Foo") %>',
    type: 'post',
    traditional: true,
    data: { values: values },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

Now let's suppose that you wanted to send the name of the checkbox as well. So that you could have the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> values)
{
    ...
}
```

where `MyViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you could send the request as JSON string. This will work out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3 because there is a `JsonValueProviderFactory` built-in capable of parsing JSON requests and binding them to strongly typed models but if you are working in older versions you could still [define this custom provider manually](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx):

```
var values = $(':checkbox').map(function () {
    return { name: this.name, isChecked: $(this).is(':checked')};
}).toArray();

$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("Foo") %>',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ values: values }),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please can you explain, what I should do if I have  2-3 groups of checkboxes.

Comment: @Sergii, that depends on what do you want to do. Do you want to send only a certain group? If yes, then simply wrap the group checkboxes into a div and adapt your CSS selector: `$('#groupWrapper :checkbox')`. Or give them a specific class and then `$('.foo:checkbox')`